# AWS PHP SDK: How to package a template?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

Our AWS architecture uses a few .sh scripts to create a stack, then a bastion and a few other things.

I'm trying to migrate these scripts to PHP scripts using the `aws-sdk-php` package.

I had this command in a package.sh file:

`aws cloudformation package --template ./master.yaml --s3-bucket rl-deploy --s3-prefix $1 --output-template-file master-packaged.yaml`

Unfortunately, the `aws-sdk-php` doesn't seem to have a `package` function.

Does it mean what I'm trying to do is not doable thanks to PHP?

If it's possible, how could I proceed without this command?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to find any answer or solution to this yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I had to execute the SH script through PHP and not through the SDK